# passing arguments with special characters to a function in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a function to which I am passing arguments like this.. (as read from a line in a text file)

```
my_proj -x build
```

but the function takes the entire string as one argument `my_proj -x build` instead of giving me `$1 = my_proj, $2=-x, $3=build`, so that I can do some operations depending on the arguments.

Any suggestions on how I can make shell scripts behave this way?

**EDIT:** Here's the code segment (added from OP's comment):

```
lines=cat $1 
IFS=$'\n' 
for line in $lines; do 
    echo "starting build for $line"
    if [ -z "$line" ] 
    then 
        continue 
    fi 
    runBuild $line
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The code shown in your comment is rather tortuous.  The problem you have is your use of `IFS`, which is tripping you up for other variable expansions.  `IFS` technique can be useful, but it can be dangerous as well.  In this case it is totally unnecessary, as is your use of `cat`.

This works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

runBuild() {
    echo "\$1: $1"
    echo "\$2: $2"
    echo "\$3: $3"
}

while read line
do 
    echo "starting build for $line" 
    runBuild $line 
done < "gash.txt"
```

Contents of `gash.txt`:

```
my_proj -x build
```

Output:

```
starting build for my_proj -x build
$1: my_proj
$2: -x
$3: build
```

Comment: that worked! i ended up using IFS as part of multiple different attempts to get it working. Had a simple for loop first but it was splitting each line at whitespace characters. anyways this worked!

Comment: @endless: Good!  A tip:  if you are going to play with `IFS`, save the old value first, like `oldIFS="$IFS"` then restore it when you are done.  Also `IFS` can be used with `read` as shown by @Jahid.  Remember that `IFS` is also used for `$@` glue as well.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when i have multiple lines in the file. It breaks out of the while loop after running build for the first line. strangely if I just comment out the line "runBuild $line" then it correctly loops through all lines!

Comment: @endless:  Have you changed `runBuild` in any way, does it include an `exit`?  Can you give some sample lines so I can try?  Also, put an `echo` after the loop to see if it is exiting.  Now run with `bash -x script-name`.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your comment:

> I am reading the command from a line in a text file, and the line in
>   the file is my_proj -x build Now, my script reads that line into a
>   variable 'var' and calls a function build() {},

I think you want this:

Use:

```
eval "build $var"
```

instead of `build $var`

Or you can change your code to omit out the `IFS=$'\n'` so that `build $var` works as expected . (`$var` needs to be unquoted)

[And you shouldn't use cat and for loop to read line from file.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Instead use a while loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line;do
#do something
done <filepath
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is where you are calling the function.

When you call the function do not pass the arguments in double quotes, in which case the entire string with spaces is treated as a single entity.

Rather than that pass without double quotes

**Test**

```
$ fun()
> {
> echo $1, $2, $3
> }

# Calling the function without double quotes
$ fun my_proj -x build
my_proj, -x, build

# Calling the function with double quotes
$ fun "my_proj -x build"
my_proj -x build, ,
$
```

If you are passing variables to the function

```
$ var="my_proj -x build"
$ fun $var
my_proj, -x, build
$ fun "$var"
my_proj -x build, ,
```

Comment: I am infact calling with out any double quotes. I am reading the command from a text file, and the line in the file is

Comment: In that case you must be providing the relevant code whereby you read the lines from the file. That would provide extra information

Comment: I am infact calling with out any double quotes. I am reading the command from a line in a text file, and the line in the file is

my_proj -x build

Now, my script reads that line into a variable 'var' and calls a function build() {}, with that argument.

build $var

but still the whole thing is taken in as one argument as seen by echo $1. not sure why as your example above shows you are getting them as multiple arguments.

Comment: lines=`cat $1`
        IFS=$'\n'
        for line in $lines; do
                echo "starting build for $line"
                if [ -z "$line" ]
                then
                        continue
                fi

                runBuild $line
        done

Comment: @endless:  The `IFS` is the problem, see my post.